# Arrowheads not falling in line

Tags: graphics3d

This is not a serious problem, but sometimes quite annoying. Say you are drawing a line with multiple `Arrowheads`.

```
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.05, 10]], 
 Arrow[{Cos[1 #] Sin[#], Sin[1 #] Sin[#], Cos[#]} & /@ 
 Range[0, Pi, Pi/20]]}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

You will often notice that some arrowheads are not exactly falling in line. For example consider this two views of the above plot.

> **Pos1 :**  ViewPoint -> {-2.85453, 1.2761, 1.29354}, ViewVertical -> {-0.500382, 0.183557, 0.846123}
>
> **Pos2 :** ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}, ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}

[image]

As you can see, **Pos1** gives a nice view, but for **Pos2** one arrowhead leaves the line in the right hand side. The way I fix it is by taking different number of arrowheads and views and choose the best one. I was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

As I can understand, this problem appears whenever the line takes a sharp bend. If there is a way to remove arrowhead (or reduce the size) at those points, that might work.

For a better demonstration of this effect check this  [Curved Arrows with Dynamic Arrowhead Positions](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/enhanced-2d-and-3d-graphics/curved-arrows-with-dynamic-arrowhead-positions.html) and look at the turning points.

Comment: Workaround: `Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.05, 10]], Black, Arrow[Tube[{Cos[1 #] Sin[#], Sin[1 #] Sin[#], Cos[#]} & /@ Range[0, Pi, Pi/20]]]}, BoxRatios -> 1]`.

Comment: That's a clever one @J.M. The arrowheads looks like from stone age though, but it is good enough for the hunt ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be looking for the option `Appearance -> "Projected"` which produces a different rendering:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.05, 10], Appearance -> "Projected"], 
  Arrow[{Cos[1 #] Sin[#], Sin[1 #] Sin[#], Cos[#]} & /@ Range[0, Pi, Pi/20]]
 }, 
 BoxRatios -> 1
]
```

[image]

This does keep the arrow "in line" but the arrow will disappear when the line of sight is tangent to that point on the line.

J. M.'s use of [`Tube`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html) gives 3D rendering of the arrowheads as little cones, but these are not recognizable as arrows from behind so this may not be an improvement over `"Projected"`.  The use of `BoxRatios` also causes the 3D arrowheads to be distorted in a likely undesirable way.

Comment: Nice! (+1) Is that a supported option? I don't see it in the documentation for `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @Edmund, it's an option for `Arrowheads[]`, actually.

Comment: LOL! Miss read it. Too long in front of the screen.