# Arrowhead scale keeps changing as figure is rotated

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am using a combination of Plot3D and Graphics3D to plot a surface based on a function and a primitive Arrow object.

```
Show[Plot3D[x^4 y + x y^2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 300}], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.005], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 200}}]}]]
```

Note this is one line of code in Mathematica but I have divided it into 3 lines here for clarity.

The output does show the desired result, namely a surface with an arrow pointing from `{0,0,0}` to `{2,2,200}` but the arrowhead is absolutely huge and varies in size as I rotate the figure in 3D.[image]

Using the `Arrowheads[]`command does make the arrowhead relatively smaller but the variability is still there even as I rotate the image very slightly.

Why does Mathematica not automatically scale these primitive objects and how can I fix this?

Comment: Does it solve your problem [Arrowheads not falling in line](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115910/arrowheads-not-falling-in-line)

Comment: @Sumit It does not. The problem is the distortion of box ratios.