# Changing Size of Arrowheads in Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, arrowhead

The size of Arrowheads in Graphics3D seems to depend on both the scale of the plot and the rotation angle. The code below plots a rotating vector moving along another vector. With `PlotRange` set to 'plotRange1' the plot looks fine but with 'plotRange2' the two arrows have unequal sizes, the size of the rotating vector changes as the vector moves and both arrowheads change when the 3D plot is rotated. Is there a way to fix the size of the arrowhead, or at least limit its huge changes?

```
plotRange1 = {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}};
plotRange2 = {{-4, 8}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}};
myPlotRange = plotRange2;
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{t/10, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tt}, 
   PlotRange -> myPlotRange, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotLabel -> "PlotRange" == plotRange1],
  ParametricPlot3D[{t, 0, 0}, {t, -4, 40}, PlotStyle -> Red],
  Graphics3D[{
    Red,
    Arrow[{{tt/10, 0, 0}, {tt/10, Cos[tt], Sin[tt]}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]
    }]
  ],
 {tt, 2, 40, 0.1}
 ]
```

[image]

This is related to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134284/arrowhead-scale-keeps-changing-as-figure-is-rotated) which was asked 5 years ago but has no answer. I am on Mathematica 13.0.1.0 for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Arrowheads[.02]` and `Tube` seems work.( we also set `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}` to make the light not so darker.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t/10, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tt}, 
   PlotRange -> myPlotRange, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotLabel -> "PlotRange" == plotRange1], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{t, 0, 0}, {t, -4, 40}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Arrowheads[.02], 
    Arrow[Tube@{{tt/10, 0, 0}, {tt/10, Cos[tt], Sin[tt]}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]}]], {tt, 2, 40, 0.1}]
```