# Rendering of arrowheads in 3D

Tags: plotting, vector

I have a vector-valued function and vectors have been drawn with `Arrow` for visualization purposes.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r[t_] := {Sqrt[t], 1/(t - 1), Sin[t]};

ptsCurve = Select[(r[#] & /@ Range[0, 40, 4]), AllTrue[NumericQ]]

Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 40}
  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]
  , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
  , SphericalRegion -> True
  ]
 , Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point /@ ptsCurve
   , Black, Thin, Arrowheads[0.03]
   , Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 0.02] & /@ ptsCurve
   }
  ]
```

[image]

Is there an option to improve the rendering of arrowheads? I have seen [276991](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276991/changing-size-of-arrowheads-in-graphics3d) but setting `Arrowheads` size does not help.

I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. This behavior is ever so slightly different on the free cloud account as well.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}` affect the arrows.

Comment: `BoxRatios` does not improve the rendering on my system.

Comment: I usually use `Arrow@Tube[...,radius]` to get nicer looking arrows in 3D. Does that work for you?

Comment: If I could adapt [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265381/putting-a-graphics3d-primitive-on-a-plot3d) for 3D arrowheads, it would be the solution. Without `BoxRatios->{1,1,1}`, the plots for many functions get flattened and can't be easily visualized. @LukasLang

Comment: Have you tried using one of the symbolic sizes Tiny, Small, Medium or Large?

Comment: @CarlWoll Not yet, could you please show me how to do it? In the mean time, I have also found a repository function that seems to do what I want.

Comment: I mean, use something like `Arrowheads[Medium]` instead of `Arrowheads[.03]`.

Comment: Yes, it works and I am deeply embarrassed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Don't scale to much in the parts of a combined graphics. It's designed for use of primitives by autoscaling. Avoid using 2d graphics primitves, their scaling to 3D is not working as expected by the user.

```
ptsCurve = Select[(r[#] & /@ Range[0, 40, 4]), AllTrue[NumericQ]];

gr = Graphics3D[{{Red, 
     Opacity[0.4], (Sphere[#, 0.1] &) /@ 
      ptsCurve}, ({Opacity[0.2], RandomColor[], 
        Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 0.03]]} &) /@ ptsCurve}];

pp = ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 40}];

 PolarVector := Function[{r, \[Phi], \[Theta]},
     r {Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], 
        Cos[\[Theta]] }]
```

Now simply combine and chose a view point

```
  Show[{pp, gr}, ViewPoint -> 
   PolarVector[12, RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
                    RandomReal[{0,\[Pi]}]], 
      PlotRange -> 5 {{-0.2, 1}, {-0.2, 1}, {-0.20, 1}}]
```

[image: Curve, points, arrows 3D]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please say more about the technique used to calculate `Viewpoint` and also fix syntax.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. For example, when we add `BoxRatios->1` .

Comment: Apparently the answer is to write 3D code.  After years to combine 2D and 3D rendering, I have given up. Graphics is a branch of art, not the question how to tweak Picassos options to generate a Rodin.

Answer (score 3):

Using the function [PlotVector3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotVector3D/) from the Wolfram Function Repository:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
r[t_] := {Sqrt[t], 1/(t - 1), Sin[t]};
ptsCurve = Select[(r[#] & /@ Range[0, 40, 4]), AllTrue[NumericQ]]

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 40}
  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
  , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
  , SphericalRegion -> True
  , ImageSize -> 600
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}
  ]
 , Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point /@ ptsCurve
   , Red, AbsolutePointSize[12]
   , Point@{0, 0, 0}
   }
  ]
 , PlotVector3D[ptsCurve
  , VectorStyle -> {{Thin, Black}}
  , "ArrowSize" -> Medium]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: The solution provided by Carl Woll in the comments is based on the documentation (Details section for `Arrowheads`) that states: `The symbolic values Tiny, Small, Medium, and Large can be used for s. With these values, the size of the arrowhead is independent of the total width of the graphic`. In the mean time, I discovered the repository function  that has additional useful features.